# Publishing does not update the published state in ITEM_STATES nor PUBLISH_STATES

Tags: 2011, publishing

*Version: Tridion 2011 SP1, no hotfixes installed*

I'm having a problem related to the publish state of items in the CM database. This problem occurred seemingly out of the blue, but it might be related to restoring our production version of the Tridion CM database on to our development system. (We do this regularly so I don't expect this to be the actual source of the problem but it's worth noting.)

Whenever I publish an item, it gets deployed properly and it comes up as "Success" in the publishing queue. Though the publish state is not changed in the CM database and the event viewer shows the following error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Component: Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing
Errorcode: 0

StackTrace Information Details:
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.PublishEngine.SetPublishToOnItems(IEnumerable`1 processedItems, Boolean isPublished, PublicationTarget publicationTarget, User publisher)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.PublishEngine.SetPublishState(IEnumerable`1 processedItems, Boolean isPublished, PublicationTarget publicationTarget, User publisher, Boolean isCalledFromFacade)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Publisher.DeploymentFeedbackHandler.SetPublishStateOnProcessedItems(TransportFeedback deploymentFeedback, PublishTransaction publishTransaction)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Publisher.DeploymentFeedbackHandler.DoWork()
```

The state is not changed, so the little 'published' icon does not show (go away) on the components/pages.

Does anyone have a clue as to where this exactly goes wrong?

More details about the development environment:
The Tridion installation on the development environment has two publication targets. Local file system and a Linux machine using sshftp. The publisher runs on the same machine as Tridion.

Comment: After restoring your database, have you changed the `IS_ONLINE` value for all the records in the `QUEUE_CONSUMERS` table? (when moving databases between environments, you should set these to 0, to prevent  notifications from being sent to the wrong servers). Also what is your exact architecture of your dev system, does it contain a separate publisher etc.?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Bart. Yes, all the fields are set to 0. I've updated my question with more information about the environment.

Comment: You mention the problem is random, ie. not happening for all your publish transactions, and I gather similar for unpublish?

Comment: With random I ment that this whole issue happened out of the blue (because we have done restores before). No publish or unpublish transaction updates the database at all.

Comment: I wouldn't have a clue, only thing I can think of is that there might be a mismatch in DB version and the actual CMS, but even then it is strange. You have tried to reboot the entire server I guess and you are able to create new items etc?

Comment: Are you using the event system, e.g. the SetPublishedTo event (legacy event system) or the save event on publish transactions (2011 event system)?

Comment: I have rebooted the entire server as well and creating items in Tridion works. We are using save events on components but we don't use events for publish transactions.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have **CM_2011.1.0.77065** applied to your environment?  This is available on [SDL Tridion World](https://www.sdltridionworld.com/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=/Images/CM_2011.1.0.77065_tcm89-20293.zip) (requires login).  The hotfix has the below description:

> This hotfix will resolve the page publish state issues for all new page publish activities. The included SQL script can be used to fix the incorrect publish state records for SQL Server and Oracle.

Comment: Thanks, I've applied fixes CM_2011.1.0.77065 as well as CM_2011.1.0.74864 but this had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Have you got the DB user permissions set correctly? Or a file somehow locked?

It is also worth checking that the DB is write enabled all orphans etc resolved.. As Bart said double check all of the connection settings too...

Comment: It is possible to write things to the database from the Tridion CMS. Are there perhaps another credentials that I don't know of that are used to update the publisher state?

Comment: Of course it is possible.. just not recommended... I was referring to the status of users etc after the restore of the database.

Comment: What I mean is that the database users are ok. I can change other things in Tridion and this all gets saved into the database correctly.